# Как получить данные из события ICQ бота

Tags: python, python-3.x, icq

ICQ бот возвращает строку вида

```
Event(type='EventType.NEW_MESSAGE', data='{'chat': {'chatId': '404484009', 'type': 'private'}, 'from': {'firstName': 'Андрей', 'userId': '404484009'}, 'msgId': '6847764087145759266', 'text': '1111', 'timestamp': 1594369320}')
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вытащить значение text из такой структуры

Answer (score 0):

Нашел подсказку на сайте icq

```
print(event.data['text'])
```